# Why are solenoidal fields called solenoidal?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, physics, fluid-dynamics

A solenoidal tangent field, mathematically speaking, is one whose divergence vanishes. They are also called incompressible. I understand why they are called incompressible — a fluid flow is called incompressible when a small fluid parcel retains constant density when it moves along along a streak line. This means that its material derivative vanishes and this in turn means that the divergence of its velocity field vanishes.

But why the description of such a field as solenoidal? I expect that this name had historical origins but it's unlikely that it was so named without some link to some aspect of what is generally meant by a solenoid. However, checking a few sources online hasn't resolved this mystery. Generally, a solenoidal field is defined mathematically as above without any discussion why it was named as such.

Now, a solenoid is a helix which suggests that a fluid particle whose velocity field is solenoidal should be moving helically. Is this because such a field would normally be rotational and so has a non-zero curl and so fluid particles in small tubes around a streakline will move helically and because the motion is also incompressible, the cross-section of this tube is constant and hence we have described a solenoid, of a kind?

Comment: Are you not satisfied with the explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field#Etymology)?

Comment: @Wojuwu: No, I'm not. And if you read my question carefully enough you will see I have checked 'online sources' including that page. It gives no real explanation of why such a field is called solenoidal other than the bald assertion " ... as if constrained within a pipe so with fixed volume". The usual sense of solenoidal means helical, as I've explained above, there is no indication of this in the Wikipedia page you linked to.

Comment: The explanation on Wikipedia is clear and not unlikely to be true, but gives no source and could be wrong.

Comment: The fact that we wind an electromagnet helically as opposed to composing it of separate rings (that we somehow must each provide with current) is a purely practical matter. It is not essential to the character of an electromagnet. I don't think a specifically helical character is attached to the notion of a solenoid.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt: It may not be essential to the character of an electromagnet, but practically speaking it's easier to wind one piece of wire round rather than many. A dictionary that I looked at described a solenoid as I expect most people would imagine it to be. Thus, I think it's natural to think of a solenoid as I have done.

Answer (score 5):

[To expand on Wojowu's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416910/why-are-solenoidal-fields-called-solenoidal#comment1069786_416910).]

**Q:** *"Why the description of a divergence-free field as solenoidal? I expect that this name had historical origins but its unlikely that it was so named without some link to some aspect of what is generally meant by a solenoid."*

**A:** The name *solenoid* for a helical coil was invented by Ampère (1823), who is quoted as follows in [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid)

> l'assemblage de tous les circuits qui l'entourent,
> assemblage auquel j'ai donné le nom de solénoïde électro-dynamique, du
> mot grec σωληνοειδὴς, dont la signification exprime précisement ce qui
> a la forme d'un canal, c'est-à-dire la surface de cette forme sur
> laquelle se trouvent tous les circuits.

<sub>the assembly of all the circuits around it, to which I have given the name of electro-dynamic solenoid, from the Greek word σωληνοειδὴς, the meaning of which expresses precisely what has the shape of a channel, that is to say the surface of this form on which all the circuits are located.</sub>

The magnetic field lines created by a solenoid are divergence free, which motivates the general name "solenoidal" for a divergence free field; it might be possible to locate some early incidences of this use, but the link to Ampère's solenoid seems beyond debate.

[image]

Comment: I don’t know whether it helps, but the Classical Greek word that Ampère based his definition on, sōlēn. means/meant a pipe.

Comment: yes, Ampère translates it as "channel" --- which I guess means the same.

Comment: σωληνοειδής is (modern) greek for "pipe-like"